# XML cacheManger bean : Multiple CachingProviders error

Tags: spring, ehcache, spring-cache, jcache

hello so I used to use one single cache provider to manage my caches but now I have to use more than one
and I'm getting some problem in init my bean in fact I get this error :

is there any possibility to define a specific provider for my XML bean?

```
   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jCacheManager' defined in class path resource [default-beans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.cache.CacheException: Multiple CachingProviders have been configured when only a single CachingProvider is expected
```

my bean

```
 <bean id="jCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheManagerFactoryBean">
          <property name="cacheManagerUri" value="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
        </bean>
        <bean id="DefaultCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheCacheManager" scope = "singleton">
          <property name="cacheManager" ref="jCacheManager" />
        </bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<bean id="CacheProvider"
class="org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider" />
<bean id="CacheManager"
    class="org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107CacheManager"
    factory-bean="CacheProvider" factory-method="getCacheManager">
    <constructor-arg
        value='#{ new org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource("/ehcache.xml").getURI()}' />
    <constructor-arg
        value="#{ getClass().getClassLoader()}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I tried this, but getting error on  factory-method="getCacheManager".. Can not resolve getCacheManager.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use multiple cache providers then you should use annotation based cache config that will reduce your work! All you need to do is :

**Enable Annotation Based cache config.**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache https://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

        <cache:annotation-driven/> //This will allow you to use @Cache annotations.
</beans>
```

**Now, you've annotation based cache service enabled in your applications.**

---

In a class, suppose you've three methods and you want each of them to be cached in different cache providers.

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames="name", cacheManager="yourProvider") 
public Object firstMethod(){
//You can enter different cache provider configured in each cache manager for each method.
}
```

Comment: hello thanks for your quick response ! . well i am trying to build directly a bean for Eh107CacheManager from xml file , passing by spring is not possible because it works with ehcache 2.x wish is not jcache standard

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same error, here is  my xml file.

```
<bean id="cacheManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="cacheManagerUri">
        <value>classpath:ehcache.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="liteWeightBookingTemplateCache" class="org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="cacheManagerUri" ref="cacheManagerFactory"/>
    <property name="beanClassLoader">
        <value>com.core.TemplateCache</value>
    </property>
    <property name="cacheManagerProperties" ref="jcache_1H"/>
</bean>
```

I am getting compile error like "Bean must be of 'java.net.URI' type". but I could able to build the application. While starting the server, getting below error

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: null